# Access parent frame from IFRAME using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, quirks-mode

In quirks mode (IE5.5), i'm trying to acces in Javascript from my Iframe to my parent. The composition of the page is like this :

```
<frameset id="mainFrame">
    <frame name="content">
        <iframe id="window">
        </iframe
    </frame>
</frameset>
```

So the script take place in the Iframe id="window", but need to acces a label inside the frame name"content".

I can't directly acces it by a getElementById, and don't know any other way in quirks mode to make it work.

Comment: I did not know if it worked in quirks mode as the only comment stating the version said IE6+, i'm going to try the first answer to see.

Comment: Okay this question is a duplicate, i'll add in the solution of the other question that it is working in IE5+ compatible quirks mode.